# Google Map not showing the marker title

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to show the title on hovering over the marker. I'm okay if it's open by default too.

I do not want `infoWindow`.

Here's what I have so far unsuccessfully.

```
function myMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(34.131730, -117.910127);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myCenter, 
    zoom: 16,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    rotateControl: false
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var image = {
    url: 'images/marker.png',
    scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(60, 60),
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter,
    title: "Hello World!",
    icon: image
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: The posted code works for me (with the default marker): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z5hfka73/).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Where's the `Hello World!`? I don't see it in the JSFiddle demo you've shared. I checked on Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: The title is the text of the "tooltip" for the marker.  Appears when you hover the mouse over the marker.  Works in Chrome for me (on a desktop, can't hover over a marker on a mobile device).  Were you looking for a label (always displays)?

Answer (score -3):

```js
function initialize() { 


var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.89364, 2.33739); 

var mapOptions = { zoom: 13, center: myLatlng } var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng, map: map, title: 'Hello World!' }); }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); initialize();



  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
initialize();
```

Comment: Please don't only post code as answer, include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. This makes your answer more valuable and more likely to attract upvotes.